# Action url not calling method action name in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

Dear friends,

I tried to execute Spring MVC form Example web project.

When I was try to hit the url with action name corresponding view is not calling
but If try to call url with view name(/viewname.html) its getting displayed.

I have seen lot of example and am wonder why my code is not calling based on 
action name.

My Sample code:

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/login",method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String login(ModelMap model){
            model.addAttribute("message","Welcome Jagan");
            return "login";
        }
    }
```

**spring-servlet.xml:**

my servlet config file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
                xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


                <context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>

                 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
                    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
                    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
                </bean> 
            </beans>
```

**web.xml:**
My web xml looks like

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
      <display-name>SpringMVCWithJSP</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

**login.jsp:**
having some welcome content

If I try to hit the following url

```
     http://localhost:8082/SpringMVCWithJSP/test/login      => not invoking login page.

     ttp://localhost:8082/SpringMVCWithJSP/test/login.html  => successfully invoking login page .
```

My question is why the login action name not invoking directly login.jsp and instead it calling only with `.../test/login.html` and not by `.../test/login` 

Any idea to resolve this friends?

Comment: because you mapped your Servlet to respond to only requests with  `*.html` pattern.  If you do not add the `.html` to the URL the servlet will not listen to them (as it does not match the pattern)

Answer (score 0):

In you `web.xml` you have this Servlet Mapping

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

which means the servlet will respond only to those URL calls that end in `.html`.  So there is nothing to resolve.  It is working as expected

Note that if you simply leave the mapping as `*` you will be forcing the servlet to handle all requests (which may or may not be what you want).  This is not recommended as you typically would have static files (such as CSS, JS, PNG, etc) that you do not want to have to process by the servlet (it will slow your server
 down)

Comment: Hi Ochi, Thanks for your reply..In My Spring MVC proj if try hit the url http://localhost:8082/SpringMVCWithJSP/test/login  it is not calling.In My Spring MVC it is supposed to call based on the action name right? that the way I configured.If I give exact url with extension then only page showing instead of calling  through the action name (login)..

Comment: @Jagan Incorrect! - the `login.jsp` page is displayed when you enter the url with extension because of this in your spring configuration: `<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
                    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
                    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
                </bean>`  ---- Did you try debugging it?  If you put a break point inside the action (login) you will see that it does go thru it before calling the .jsp page